# PHP ¿Como contar la cantidad de Arrays?

Tags: php, array

Tengo algo similar a esto

```
Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 1
                [group] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 2
                [group] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 3
                [group] => 2
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 4
                [group] => 2
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 5
                [group] => 3
            )
)
```

pero lo que necesito es poder hacer un count a [0] => Array, [1] => Array, [2] => Array, [3] => Array, [4] => Array.

Digamos, obtener el último numero de array para poder saber la cantidad.

Lo ultimo que probe fue

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($array as $type) {
    $count+= count($type);
}
```

pero me devolvió cualquier valor.

Comment: ¿No te funciona con `count($array);`?

Comment: Me dice que tengo uno más del que realmente tengo

Comment: ¿Uno más?, ¿no será que estás manipulando el valor? `count` te cuenta lo que hay, sin tener que sumarle `1` en ninguna parte. Y sin bucles ni nada, tal cual como te lo puse.

Comment: no haz probado sizeof($array);

Comment: Directamente lo que hice, use count($array) y donde necesitaba aplicarlo le reste 1 y listo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$comida = array('frutas' => array('naranja', 'plátano', 'manzana'),
                'verduras' => array('zanahoria', 'col', 'guisante'));

// Cuenta recursiva
echo count($comida, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // muestra 8

// Cuenta normal
echo count($comida); // muestra 2

?>
```

En tu caso seria

```
$count = count($array);
```

Answer (score 1):

Primero dale un nombre a ese array principal, por ejemplo:

```
$arrayGrande = Array(
        [0] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 1
                [group] => 1
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 2
                [group] => 1
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 3
                [group] => 2
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 4
                [group] => 2
            )
        [4] => Array
            (
                [user] => Name 5
                [group] => 3
            )
)
```

y después haces un bucle, el que quieras (for, foreach, while...) con el valor $arrayGrande[0]